# Create index list from XML file then display selected content in index order

Tags: actionscript-3, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with nodes such as below for hundreds of lessons. Each lesson has multiple nodes (up to 50) in the XML file.

I want to read through the XML, pick out only the lesson nodes with the requested lesson numbers then display the data for the lesson nodes in their index number order (order of i). For example, If I want to work with Lessons 1-3, then the code determines that those lessons begin with index 0 and end with index 75. Once I have the beginning and ending index for a lesson range, I know the rest. Or if there is an easier way to do what is described, I will try it.

```
<Course>
    <i>
        <Lesson>1</Lesson>
        <Word1>tank</Word1>
        <Audio1>../audio/1s-1a.mp3</Audio1>
        <Word2>fish</Word2>
        <Audio2>../audio/1s-1b.mp3</Audio2>
    </i>
    <i>
        <Lesson>1</Lesson>
        <Word1>thought</Word1>
        <Audio1>../audio/1s-2a.mp3</Audio1>
        <Word2>action</Word2>
        <Audio2>../audio/1s-2b.mp3</Audio2>
    </i>
    <i>
        <Lesson>1</Lesson>
        <Word1>trace</Word1>
        <Audio1>../audio/1s-3a.mp3</Audio1>
        <Word2>follow</Word2>
        <Audio2>../audio/1s-3b.mp3</Audio2>
    </i>
</Course>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works by me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var data:XML = 
            <Course>
                <i>
                    <Lesson>1</Lesson>
                    <Word1>tank</Word1>
                    <Audio1>../audio/1s-1a.mp3</Audio1>
                    <Word2>fish</Word2>
                    <Audio2>../audio/1s-1b.mp3</Audio2>
                </i>
                <i>
                    <Lesson>1</Lesson>
                    <Word1>thought</Word1>
                    <Audio1>../audio/1s-2a.mp3</Audio1>
                    <Word2>action</Word2>
                    <Audio2>../audio/1s-2b.mp3</Audio2>
                </i>
                <i>
                    <Lesson>3</Lesson>
                    <Word1>trace</Word1>
                    <Audio1>../audio/1s-3a.mp3</Audio1>
                    <Word2>follow</Word2>
                    <Audio2>../audio/1s-3b.mp3</Audio2>
                </i>
                <i>
                    <Lesson>5</Lesson>
                    <Word1>trace</Word1>
                    <Audio1>../audio/1s-3a.mp3</Audio1>
                    <Word2>follow</Word2>
                    <Audio2>../audio/1s-3b.mp3</Audio2>
                </i>
            </Course>

        protected function onBtnClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var xmlList:XMLList = data.i.(Lesson >= 1 && Lesson <= 3);
            //do something
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Button label="Get Lessons" click="onBtnClick(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Yup agree OP should look up E4X on google if you're not familiar with "ECMAScript for XML" it generally helps a lot to simplify the task of filtering/searching XML data.